# WPF & RelayCommand - Button always firing

Tags: wpf, button

I have been working through some of the examples of MVVM & WPF and while doing some debugging I find that the RelayCommand associated with a button on my view is constantly firing (executing the associated ImportHoursCommand) as soon as the program starts.

Here are the code snippets:

**View**

```
<Button x:Name="ImportHoursButton" Content="Import Hours" 
        Command="{Binding ImportHoursCommand}" 
        Height="25" Width="100" Margin="10"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"                
        Grid.Row="1" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
        private RelayCommand _importHoursCommand;
        public ICommand ImportHoursCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_importHoursCommand == null)
                {
                    _importHoursCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ImportHoursCommandExecute(), 
                                                            param => this.ImportHoursCommandCanExecute);
                }
                return _importHoursCommand;
            }
        }

        void ImportHoursCommandExecute()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Import Hours",
                            "Hours have been imported!",
                            MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        bool ImportHoursCommandCanExecute
        {
            get
            {
                string userProfile = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
                string currentFile = @userProfile + "\\download\\test.txt";
                if (!File.Exists(currentFile))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File Not Found", 
                                    "The file " + currentFile + " was not found!", 
                                    MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

If I put a breakpoint on the 'string userProfile = ...' line and run the program, Visual Studio will stop on the breakpoint and continue to stop on the breakpoint everytime I click the debug 'Continue' button.  If I don't have a breakpoint the program appears to run OK but should this command always be checking if it can execute?

I am using the RelayCommand from Josh Smith's article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a Button is bound to a Command, the `CanExecute()` determines if the Button is enabled or not. This means the `CanExecute()` is run anytime the button needs to check it's enabled value, such as when it gets drawn on the screen.

Since you're using a breakpoint in VS, I am guessing that the application is getting hidden when VS gains focus, and it is re-drawing the button when you hit the Continue button. When it re-draws the button, it is evaluating `CanExecute()` again, which goes into the endless cycle you're seeing

One way to know for sure is to change your breakpoint to a `Debug.WriteLine`, and watch your output window when your application is running.

As a side note, you could also change your `RelayCommand` to Microsoft Prism's `DelegateCommand`. I haven't looked at the differences too closely, however I know `RelayCommands` automatically raise the `CanExecuteChanged()` event when certain conditions are met (properties change, visual invalidated, etc) while `DelegateCommands` will only raise this event when you specifically tell it to. This means `CanExecute()` only evaluates when you specifically tell it to, not automatically, which can be good or bad depending on your situation.

Comment: OK this makes sense then.  The examples I have been going through didn't make it clear that the CanExecute was controlling the button itself.  I thought it was a way to determine if the Command itself could be executed.

Comment: @BrianKE Nope, if you ever run your `Command.Execute()` manually, be sure to run the `Command.CanExecute()` first

Comment: @BrianKE CanExecute is there as a way for you to determine if that button has the ability to execute or not.  As Rachel said, it's always best to call the CanExecute when available, even if it's empty, as code may be added later to the CanExecute and it would automatically work.

Answer (score 3):

That's perfectly normal; WPF reevaluates whether the command can be executed very often, for instance when the focus control changes, or when the window takes focus. Every time you click "Continue", the window takes the focus again, which reevaluates the `CanExecute` of your command, so your breakpoint is hit again.

Comment: Why would this be normal behavior?  Shouldn't the command only be checked/executed when the button is pushed?  

Is there a way to only check this when the button is clicked?  When this command is executed I am doing some checking to see if a file exits, if the hours to import already exist, etc. and displaying a MessageBox to let the user know if something went wrong.  When it constantly checks the state I am getting MesasgeBoxes non-stop making the program unusable.

Comment: @BrianKE `CanExecute` determines if the Button is Enabled or not, so anytime the UI needs to re-draw the button, or anytime the RelayCommand thinks the CanExecute parameters have changed, the `CanExecute()` method will get run. You would be better off checking if a file exists or not (or other such logic) in the button's Click method, or on the FileName's PropertyChanged event.

Comment: I thought the Click method was replaced with the Command when using MVVM to maintain separation of code and view?!  Is this not the case or am I missing the point of CommandExecute()?

Comment: @BrianKE You can actually have both a Click event, and a Command on your Button. Commands get executed when the button gets clicked, and CanExecute is used to determine if the command can be run or not. I think by default CanExecute is NOT run when clicking the button to execute the command, although I haven't tested that theory. I just recall debugging some commands that should not have executed because of CanExecute, but did.